# How to display the dates of month which has no Data from database in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I wanted to show the Monthly sale of a shop, the charts show the total sales per date of the month. The below sales amount and dates are from database, I wanted to show all dates of the month (until 1-till current date) like today is 27, so it show (1-27), the date which has no sales or no data need to show 0.

[image]

```js
    import React from "react";
    import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
// API Example data {
//     "Count": 2,
//     "Result": [
//         {
//             "ID": "62d7b594466f086f718a0c1f",
//             "Name": "K",
//             "PurchaseID": "62d7b594466f086f718a0c1d",
//             "ShopOrderStatus": "Order Shipped Out",
//             "TotalOrderCost": 503.25,
//             "Courier": null,
//             "OrderDate": "2022-06-20T07:58:12.385Z"
//         },
//         {
//             "ID": "62d7b576466f086f718a0c1a",
//             "Name": "K",
//             "PurchaseID": "62d7b576466f086f718a0c18",
//             "ShopOrderStatus": "Order Shipped Out",
//             "TotalOrderCost": 824.83,
//             "Courier": null,
//             "OrderDate": "2022-07-24T07:57:42.527Z"
//         },
//     ]}

    function SalesReport() {
 const yesterday = new Date(today - 1);
  yesterday.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
 let CmonthOrder = [];
  if (isSuccess) {
// Get data from api
    CmonthOrder = data.data.Result.filter(
      (OldOrder) =>
        new Date(OldOrder.OrderDate).getMonth() === yesterday.getMonth()
    );
  }
    // seperate each date with price eg: 62d7b576466f086f718a0c1a: {24/07: 824.83}
      const Cmonth = CmonthOrder.reduce((acc, e) => {
        const date = moment(e.OrderDate).format("DD/MM");
        if (!acc[e.ID]) {
          acc[e.ID] = {
            [date]: e.TotalOrderCost,
          };
        } else {
          acc[e.ID][date] = e.TotalOrderCost;
        }
        return acc;
      }, {});
      //   Get the Order Date data
      const CmonthOrderdate = [
        ...new Set(
          Object.keys(Cmonth)
            .map((i) => Object.keys(Cmonth[i]))
            .flat()
        ),
      ];

      //   Get Sum of Order Per day of the Month
      const totalSumPerDateM = {};
      CmonthOrderdate.forEach((date) => {
        const sumOnDate = Object.values(Cmonth).reduce((acc, curr) => {
          acc += curr[date] ? curr[date] : 0;
          return acc;
        }, 0);
        totalSumPerDateM[[date]] = sumOnDate;
      });
      

      //   Get Sum Currentday Sales Amount
      const CmonthOrderdata = Object.values(totalSumPerDateM);
    // Chart for this Month SalesReport
      const chartExample3 = {
        data: (canvas) => {
          const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

          const gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(500, 0, 100, 0);
          gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, "#2CA8FF");
          gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, chartColor);

          const gradientFill = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 170, 0, 50);
          gradientFill.addColorStop(0, "rgba(128, 182, 244, 0)");
          gradientFill.addColorStop(1, hexToRGB("#2CA8FF", 0.4));
          return {
            labels: CmonthOrderdate,
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "Sales",
                backgroundColor: gradientFill,
                borderColor: "#fbc658  ",
                pointHoverRadius: 2,
                pointRadius: 1,
                fill: false,
                borderWidth: 3,
                barPercentage: 1.6,
                tension: 0.4,
                data: CmonthOrderdata,
              },
            ],
          };
        },
        options: {
          plugins: {
            legend: {
              display: false,
            },

            tooltips: {
              enabled: false,
            },
          },
          scales: {
            y: {
              ticks: {
                color: "#9f9f9f",
                beginAtZero: false,
                maxTicksLimit: 5,
              },
              grid: {
                drawBorder: false,
                display: false,
              },
            },
            x: {
              grid: {
                drawBorder: false,
                display: false,
              },
              ticks: {
                padding: 20,
                color: "#9f9f9f",
              },
            },
          },
        },
      };
      
       return (
      <div className="content">
      <Card className="card-dark">
                <CardHeader>
                  <Row>
                    <Col sm="7">
                      <div className="numbers pull-left">{`RM ${CmonthOtotal.toFixed(
                        2
                      )}`}</div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm="5">
                      <div className="pull-right">
                        <Badge color="warning" pill>
                          ~51%
                        </Badge>
                      </div>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                  <h6 className="big-title">
                    total Sales for this {moment().format("MMMM")}
                  </h6>
                  <Line
                    data={chartExample3.data}
                    options={chartExample3.options}
                    height={380}
                    width={826}
                  />
                </CardBody>
                <CardFooter>
                  <hr />
                  <Row>
                    <Col sm="7">
                      <div className="footer-title">View more details</div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm="5">
                      <div className="pull-right">
                        <Button
                          className="btn-round btn-icon"
                          color="warning"
                          size="sm"
                        >
                          <i className="nc-icon nc-alert-circle-i" />
                        </Button>
                      </div>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </CardFooter>
              </Card>
       </div>
      )

    }
```

I don't know how to show all the dates of the month even if not in the database, Need help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your datasource is `totalSumPerDateM` and it seems to be an object of type

```
{<DAY_OF_MONTH>: <SUM_OF_ORDERS_FOR_DAY>}
```

and you only have like three dates, you should pre-fill your object with each day of the month as a key with default value zero, then proceed to fill some of the zero-value keys with data from the API (as you already do).

**EXAMPLE**

```js
const totalSumPerDateM = {};
CmonthOrderdata.forEach((date) => {
  const sumOnDate = Object.values(Cmonth).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc += curr[date] ? curr[date] : 0;
    return acc;
  }, 0);
  totalSumPerDateM[[date]] = sumOnDate;
});

const datesToYesterday = [...Array(yesterday.getDate()).keys()]
  .map(k => new Date(
    yesterday.getFullYear(),
    yesterday.getMonth(),
    k+1
  ));

datesToYesterday.forEach((date) => {
  const formattedDate = moment(date).format("DD/MM");
  totalSumPerDateM[formattedDate] = totalSumPerDateM[formattedDate] || 0;
});
```

Comment: can you give an example how to do ?

Comment: Sure, I've added the example.